# Can I detect only specific labels using detect.py yolov5

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolov5

I have trained a model based on YOLOv5 on a custom dataset which has two classes (for example human and car)
I am using `detect.py` with the following command:

```
> python detect.py --weights best.pt --source video.mp4
```

I want only car class to be detected without detecting humans, how it could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify classes, which you want to detect **[--classes]** arguments will be used.

**Example**

```
python detect.py --weights "your weights.pt" --source "video/image/stream" --classes 0,1,2
```

In above command, 0,1,2 are classId, so when you will run it, only mentioned classes will be detect.

Comment: a little correction :

python detect.py --weights "your weights.pt" --source "video/image/stream" --classes 0 1 2

Notice that in the classes argument, the class indexes are separated by space only (not by comma)
source : https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/3b41c2cc709628a8c1966931e696b14c11d6db0c/detect.py#L178

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the argument --classes of detect.py. Just use the index of the classes.